# ESLint rule to block users from disabling ESLint rules

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have a project with very few ESLint rules that are mandatory for all the collaborators, unfortunately, I've found some developers have disabled some rules with no justification and the Code Review failed to stop this. Is there a way to configure ESLint to ignore comments disabling rules or for it to throw warnings whenever this happens?

I've been looking for a while and haven't found anything of the sort. Is there maybe another way to do this?

Comment: gitlab enterprise and github team has the feature to lock the .eslintrc file so no one has permission to change it

Comment: @arslan2012 I'm specifically referring to the comments `/* eslint-disable */` put in files by other programmers

Comment: You can probably add a checklist in the PR template and have an item stating that you should do you best to lint your code or at least leave comments for code where an eslint-disable is used.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wow, very cool scenario. But I feel sorry for the developers who might want to kick me for answering this. Follow the below steps

```
npm install --save-dev eslint eslint-plugin-eslint-comments
```

in your `.eslintrc.*` file add

```
{
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:eslint-comments/recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "eslint-comments/no-use": ["error", {"allow": []}]
    }
}
```

For more info check this link https://mysticatea.github.io/eslint-plugin-eslint-comments/rules/no-use.html

Comment: Is this rule still working today? I see nothing when enabling it as shown above, and no eslint errors in the log.